# Fetch API call not fetching cookies in expo react native?

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, axios, expo

I'm trying to send a post request to the server but the response does not contain 'set-cookie' header but the cookie is visible in postman.

This is the code:

```
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
    let config = {
        method: 'post',
        url: 'https://app.bhive.fund/v1/api/account/signin',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        data: form
    }
    const res = await axios(config)
    console.log(res.status)
    console.log('set-cookie: ');
    console.log(res.headers['set-cookie']);
    console.log(res.headers);
    return res;
```

[This is the screenshot of the log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6zj4c.png)

[This is the screenshot of postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4jpnp.png)

Answer (score 0):

That's because of the res.headers can't be accessed like an object.
You have to use the get()-method specified in order to get the cookie.

Try this instead of accessing the value right away by specifying the index with the brackets:

```js
   console.log(res.headers.get("Set-Cookie"));
```